# DeckGL with React – JSX wrapper component for Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl, deck.gl

I'm using DeckGL with React + Typescript and I'm looking to find a way to create a wrapper component for the Map component from [react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/get-started/get-started) to handle its own functionalities.

Currently I have an implementation working, but the Map component has to be a direct child of DeckGL, like so:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <DeckGL ...>
      <Map .../>
    </DeckGL>
}
```

However, what I'd like to achieve is taking the Map component in a separate file where a props could be passed and state could be handled:

MapWrapper.tsx

```
const MapWrapper = (props) => {
  // Handle state here, perhaps make use of useEffect()
  return <Map .../>
}
```

App.tsx

```
import MapWrapper from "./MapWrapper"
const App = () => {
  return (
    <DeckGL ...>
      <MapWrapper .../>
    </DeckGL>
}
```

The caveat stated [here](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/react/deckgl#jsx-layers) says JSX layers of deckgl are converted to object instances as they are not true React components, however I'm not sure if the same is true for the Map component from react-map-gl.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think the Map Component actually depends on the DeckGL Component. So a workaround could be to make a wrapper Component for the DeckGL Component. Then you have a component where you can handle state and props.

so something like this:

```
<Wrapper ...>
  <DeckGL ...>
    <Map .../>
  </DeckGL>
</Wrapper>
```